# Finding GPS Exif in Hex?

Tags: hex, exif

I'm looking for GPS metadata inside a photo. I know I can use ExifTool and many other tools but I want to analyse the photograph at hex level. So I read that Exif metadata is stored in an APP1 section and there may be more than one APP1 section. The application data in an Exif
APP1 section begins with: `45 78 69 66 00 00` So I looked around there, but nothing.

I then looked at the exif-spec for GPS (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html) and it said that latitude is at offset 0x0002. Offset 0x0002 is the header of the JPG (`FF D8 FF`).

At the top of the top of the exif GPS specs, it says that the tags may be in a different IFD(image
file directory) within the exif information.

So I'm a bit confused now. Anyone know a proven method of viewing GPS exif in hex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  ExifTool to the rescue:

1) exiftool -htmldump image.jpg > out.html

2) open "out.html" with your favourite web browser

As far as I know, ExifTool is the best (only?) hex dump utility for TIFF/EXIF metadata.